# jquery validation didn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

I have this code for validation but it show error even it returns true. I change all return false to true but error is shown. 
second I want show result.message instead "username is already taken".

```
    $.validator.addMethod("uniqueUserName", function (value, element) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/validation/search",
            data: {
                nationalCode: $('#karkonan_MelliCode').val(),
                personType: $('#karkonan_MelliatCode').val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
               // alert(result.message);
               // alert(result.resultCode);
                // if the user exists, it returns a string "true"
                if (result.resultCode == "0") {
                    alert($('#karkonan_MelliatCode').val());// already exists
                    //j = result.message;// already exists
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    alert($('#karkonan_MelliatCode').val());
                    return true;      // username is free to use
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                // if the user exists, it returns a string "true"
                alert("error");
                return false;
                // username is free to use
            }
        })
    }, "Username is Already Taken");
```

and it's rule is :

```
'karkonan.MelliCode': {
                        number:true,
                        minlength: 10,
                        maxlength: 10,
                        required: true,
                        withmelliat:true,
                        uniqueUserName: true
                    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addMethod` probably want a callback response immediately.

You perform an Ajax and the response is async. `return` statements in your `success` and `error` handlers don't apply for the `addMethod` return value (done immediately after the Ajax request and before responses).

To check that, add a `return true;` here:

```
    });
    return true;
}, "Username is Already Taken");
```

I havn't the solution yet, I have (and you have) to read your [validator plugin documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod).

You also have to read the `remote` property of this plugin: [here the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).

Comment: How about dynamic result.message? can I show dynamic message?

Comment: it's ok. I found how can I use dynamic message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `error` is function to be called **if the AJAX request fails**, not if your script returns some error! 
The function receives three arguments:

The `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, `XMLHttpRequest`) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.

Possible values for the second argument (besides `null`) are `timeout`, `error`, `abort`, and `parsererror`. When an HTTP error occurs, `errorThrown` receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as `Not Found` or `Internal Server Error`.

As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. 
Note: This handler is **not called for cross-domain** script and cross-domain JSONP requests.

Controversially, the `success` is a function to be called **if the AJAX request itself  succeeds**, i.e. if the browser can send the request properly.

The function gets passed three arguments:

The data returned from the server, formatted according to the `dataType` parameter; a string describing the status; and the `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.